# How to render bunch of strings in React native

Tags: react-native

Am building a small react native app where users can read about some of the tax laws.
I hold the data (bunch of strings) on data.js which I render on the App tabs.
But the App becomes too slow when navigating from Home Page to the tab, maybe, because of the bunch of strings that I'm rendering.
Please, is there a better way on how to render huge strings (not list) in react native and the app will be fast?

Here's sample of the tab:

```
import dataOne from './data';
function TabOneContents(){
    return(
      <ScrollView>
        <MyDivider>
        <Text>About Finance Act 2019</Text>
        <MyDivider/>
        
        <View>
          <Text>{dataOne.pgOne[1]}</Text>
          <Text>{dataOne.pgOne[2]}</Text>
            {dataOne.pgOne.slice(3,8).map((item, index)=>{
              return  <Text key={`${index}+unique1`}>
                        {`\u2022 ${item}`}
                      </Text>
            })
          }        
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>{dataOne.pgOne[8]}</Text>
          <Text>{dataOne.pgOne[9]}</Text>
          <Text>{dataOne.pgOne[10]}</Text>
          {dataOne.pgOne.slice(11,15).map((item, index)=>{
            return <Text key={`${index}+unique2`}>{`\u2022 ${item}`}</Text>
          })}
          <Text>{dataOne.pgOne[15]}</Text>
          {dataOne.pgOne.slice(16,20).map((item, index)=>{
            return <Text key={`${index}+unique3`} style={styles.cont1Text2}>{`\u2022 ${item}`}</Text>
          })} 
          <Text>{dataOne.pgOne[20]}</Text>
          <Text>{dataOne.pgOne[21]}</Text>
          {dataOne.pgOne.slice(22,26).map((item, index)=>{
            return <Text key={`${index}+unique4`}>{`\u2022 ${item}`}</Text>
          })}
          <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, paddingTop:10}}>{dataOne.pgOne[26]}</Text>
          {dataOne.pgOne.slice(27,31).map((item, index)=>{
            return <Text key={`${index}+unique5`} style={styles.cont1Text2}>{`\u2022 ${item}`}</Text>
          })}       
        </View>
        <MyDivider/>

        <View style={[styles.container1,{backgroundColor: '#ff23'}]}>
          <Text style={styles.cont1Text1}>{dataOne.pgOne[31]}</Text>
          {dataOne.pgOne.slice(32,35).map((item, index)=>{
            return <Text key={`${index}+unique6`} style={styles.cont1Text2}>{`\u2022 ${item}`}</Text>
          })}     
        </View>
        <MyDivider/>
      </ScrollView>
  )
}

export {TabOneContents};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the flatList instead the scrollView maybe ...
flatList are preferable for large amount of data.